# unrecognized selector sent to... NSArray (but I'm not using an NSArray)

Tags: objective-c, macos, exception, selector

I'm catching a `SIGABRT` on Mac OS X 10.8.3 and Xcode 4.6.3:

```
2013-09-20 06:31:02.676 groupinfo[958:303] -[__NSArrayI stringByAppendingString:]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100408850
...
2013-09-20 07:13:29.575 groupinfo[987:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'
```

The `SIGABRT` is occurring at line 41 below, but I'm not using a `NSArray` in that area:

```
32  NSArray *results = [query resultsAllowingPartial:NO error:nil];
33  for (ODRecord *record in results) {
34   
35      NSArray* group = [NSArray arrayWithObject:kODAttributeTypePrimaryGroupID];
36      NSDictionary* dict = [record recordDetailsForAttributes:group error:nil];
37      
38      NSString* str = @"";
39      if(dict) {
40          str = [str stringByAppendingString:[dict valueForKey:kODAttributeTypePrimaryGroupID]];
41          str = [str stringByAppendingString:@"  "];
42      }
43
44      str = [str stringByAppendingString:[record recordName]];
45      NSLog(@"%@", str);
46  }
```

I verified the value from the dictionary at line 40 is a `NSString`.

Any ideas why `stringByAppendingString` is being sent to an array and not `str`? Or is there a hidden array somewhere and I'm missing some obvious expected behavior?

Comment: It seems that `[dict valueForKey:kODAttributeTypePrimaryGroupID]` is not a NSString kind.

Comment: Thanks Kirsteins. I believe that use is consistent with Apple's example at [Open Directory Programming Guide, Working with Records and Queries](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/networking/Conceptual/Open_Directory/workingWithRecords/workingWithRecords.html). Take a look at how they fetch phone numbers with `kODAttributeTypePhoneNumber`.

Comment: Thanks again Kirsteins. You were right - the problem was on line 40, even though I did not get any errors from the statement. When I added the `objectAtIndex:0`, the problem went away. You should answer so I can give you the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to the uncought exception in the logs - `NSInvalidArgumentException`. So argument and not method names causes unrecognized selector error. It seems that

```
[dict valueForKey:kODAttributeTypePrimaryGroupID]
```

is not a NSString kind.